# JQuery addition of selection not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I have this code where I'm adding a select option upon pressing an add button. The problem is that I'm getting the option values outside of the select dropdown. Everything seems to be alright but then the output is just weird. Could you guys have a look at it?

This is the `div` where the content is to be placed.

```
<div id="here"></div>
```

This is the add button

```
<div class="form-group col-auto">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="trigger" style="float: left">Add an item</button>
</div>
```

This is the js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var val = $('#numoforders').val();
$('#trigger').click(function(){
val++;
$("#here").append('<div class="row">');
$("#here").append('<div class="form-group">');
$("#here").append('Select category');
$("#here").append('<select class="form-control" id="category_id['+val+']" name="category_id['+val+']">');
$("#here").append('<option selected>--Select a category--</option>');
@foreach($categories as $category) 
$("#here").append('<option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>');
@endforeach
$("#here").append('</select>');
$("#here").append('</div>');
$("#here").append('</div>');        
});
</script>
```

categories is a variable passed from the controller, and I'm using laravel.

[image: This is the result observed]

As observed in the image, the output is just weird. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are appending incomplete html and the browser is trying to compensate for that

Comment: You're appending everything to the element with id `here` and that happens to be a `<div>`. so the output is as it should be. What else could it be if you append an option element to a div?

Comment: @PatrickEvans is right. When you append a `<div>` tag for instance JQuery will add a div tag but also close it immediately.

Comment: in addition, i suggest the selecors should be reused instead of calling multiple times.

Comment: Thank you everybody. Yeah I was missing a bit of information on what .append does. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each opening element tag is added to the DOM the browser tried to close it, therefore, the `select` tag is closed before the `options` tags are added. Try adding the entire markup to the DOM in one `append`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var val = $('#numoforders').val();
$('#trigger').click(function(){
val++;
html = '<div class="row">'
  + '<div class="form-group">'
  + 'Select category'
  + '<select class="form-control" id="category_id['+val+']" name="category_id['+val+']">'
  + '<option selected>--Select a category--</option>'
  + '<option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>';

@foreach($categories as $category) 
html += '<option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>';
@endforeach

html += '</select></div></div>';

$("#here").append(html);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much mhatch. I didn't know that jQuery closes the opening tag at every append. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not the jQuery, it's the browser. When you append an opening tag, the browser tries to complete it and closes it for you.